# Change default slim views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4 with the Slim gem.

I would like change the default views generated with the command:

```
rails g controller Foo
```

I have Slim as template engine by default but I want other html in the templates.

Comment: Use `slim-rails` gem instead, in does what you're after.

Comment: Ok, I have installed slim-rails, but where are templates by default? For instance, I want change html for all views type "show.html.slim" generated with this command. I am looking for in 'lib/templates/' but they are not. What is the path for this views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently slim doesn't generate `.slim` files for views, it will be Rails default `.erb` files. You can actually convert your erb files to slim, here are some references:

- [How convert your .erb to .slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/wiki/Template-Converters-ERB-to-SLIM)
- [HTML2slim](https://html2slim.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: I have already files with .slim extension what I need is change the default html generated.

Comment: Sorry buddy but there's no other way than doing it manually or use https://github.com/slim-template/slim-rails gem to generate slim files in future generate command. You will have to change those HTML files with the converters I listed. I was also looking for something like that but unfortunately couldn't find.